# Settings API: Change position of custom setting field

Tags: options, settings-api

I've searched high and low on Google and this site for an answer to this and am quite surprised to find nothing about it anywhere

I've added a custom setting to the General settings tab using `add_settings_field()` but the field appears at the bottom of the page.

I'd like the field to appear below the Email field but I can't find any documentation or anything on how to change the position of it

Is there a filter on the settings field I can hook on to manipulate the order in which the fields are displayed and inject my custom field where desired?

Comment: Dang, this is a great question, too bad there's no answer. In `add_settings_field()` we see that it stores the results in `global $wp_settings_fields;`, so altering that array should theoretically give us an avenue to re-order our option within the core fields, BUT for some reason the core fields aren't in there!